# difference beween armv7 and armv7a in poky meta source

Tags: arm, yocto, gcc4

Initially I was assuming that armv7 and armv7a both are same, but while checking the `meta/conf/machine/include/arm/arch-armv7a.inc` file in the poky meta source, following statement says armv7a is conflicting with armv7.

```
TUNECONFLICTS[armv7a] = "armv4 armv5 armv6 armv7"
```

Similarly I could see armv7a and armv7at also in the same file.

Can you please help me to understand the difference between armv7, armv7a and armv7at

Comment: likely need to dig deeper into the documentation or the code to find what armv7 and armv7a define for that source, and then compare them.

Comment: After digging more, It seems a for application processor in armv7a and t for thumb in armv7at based on the variable assignment. But not sure about the difference between armv7a and armv7.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the cross-compiler compilation, stage number 1 and 2, you configure gcc with --with-arch=ARCH flag. These flags you are pointing are used for setting up that. Each one sets different cross-compiler options dependent of target platform (some with litte endian, some with big endian, and so on). Check you target platform for more details.